# Подать функцию в шаблон. С++

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

Добрый день.

Возникла задача, написать 4 функции которые будут различаться лишь подаваемыми типами и одной строкой в теле. При этом хотелось бы сделать это как можно более лаконично и изящно.

Мне показалось, что будет здорово написать шаблон и в качестве параметра передавать функцию, которая будет определять нужную строку. Примерно это у меня в голове должно выглядеть так:

```
template<class inType, class outType>
void defOp(const inType& IN1,const inType& IN2,outType& res, <FUNCTION>)
{   
    res = FUNCTION(IN1,IN2)
};
```

Хотелось бы понять как нужно подать в шаблон эту FUNCTION. Причем вызывать функцию хотелось бы, например, так:

```
defOp(IN1,IN2,res,add);
defOp(IN1,IN2,res,mult);
```

И как следует описывать add и mult?

Comment: А чего вы ходите добиться используя такой шаблон? Вы можете вызывать функции и без него `res = add(IN1, IN2); res = mul(IN1, IN2);`. Использование шаблона тут ничего не дает. Или используйте готовый `std::invoke`.

Comment: Да, тут ничего, но это только пример не захламленный лишними подробностями.

Comment: а что такое <inType>? Вы сначала изучайте  шаблоны а потом пытайтесь написать шаблонные функции

Comment: Как связаны `in1` и `in2` c `iF` и `sF`, если вообще связаны? Это просто опечатка или что-то иное?

Comment: Прошу прощения опечатался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить иметь возможность передавать в свою функцию любые "вызываемые" (callable) объекты, то либо

```
template<typename inType, typename outType, typename F>
void defOp(const inType &in1, const inType &in2, outType& res, F f)
{   
  res = f(in1, in2);
}
```

либо

```
template<typename inType, typename outType>
void defOp(const inType &in1, const inType &in2, outType& res,
           std::function<outType (inType, inType)> f)
{   
  res = f(in1, in2);
}
```

Во втором случае вы немножко жертвуете производительностью для того, чтобы избавиться от одного шаблонного параметра.

Если же общий тип передаваемой функции вам заранее известен и фиксирован, то его можно впрямую указать в качестве типа параметра. Например, если вы знаете, что передавать будете только обычные функции, то

```
template<typename inType, typename outType>
void defOp(const inType &in1, const inType &in2, outType& res,
           outType f(inType, inType))
{   
  res = f(in1, in2);
}
```

хотя никакой экономии над предыдущими вариантами такая конкретика не дает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, он мне очень помог, но вот возникает дополнительный вопрос, что делать если при вызове такой вот строки
`defOp(IN1,IN2,res,add);`
Мне выпадает следующая ошибка:
`invalid use of non-static member function add`
 Кажется, я не очень понимаю как теперь обратится к своему шаблону.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class inType, class outType, typename Function>
void defOp(const inType& IN1, const inType& IN2, outType& res, Function func)
{   
    res = func(IN1,IN2);
};
```

Comment: : error: iF and  sF was not declared in this scope

      ^

Comment: @ARHovsepyan это код ТС'а, ему виднее. Может быть там должны быть IN1, IN2, но я без понятия.

Comment: ну я так - это не замечание, просто логично чтоб там были  arg1 и arg2,